# Missing form data via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to hunt down a bug in a register form I have. Every now and then I'll get an error of some undefined indexes. The forms are submitted using `$('#theFormId').serialize()`.

My guess is in some browsers, in some cases `.serialize()` is missing out blank fields. Are there any reasons anyone knows why `.serialize()` could be doing this? The fields aren't disabled so I don't think that could be an issue.

I could solve the issue by putting in and `!isset($form['theField'])` check in (which I probably will anyway) but I'd like to find the reason the field isn't being posted through in the first place.

Comment: add a sample demo fiddle to examine it

Comment: on which browser you are facing issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've only just added that to the log, and that error hasn't come in since so until it gets trigger again by someone I don't know.

Comment: If you have an unclosed `<div>` tag in your form, posting the form will output nothing in some browsers